# What is the semantics of a Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines, operational-semantics, denotational-semantics

Can we formalize the operational/denotational semantics of a Turing Machine? Is there any formalization in literature?

Comment: Isn't a universal Turing machine exactly that - a formalisation of the operational semantics of a Turing machine - since it can reproduce the behaviour of any Turing machine given any input ?

Comment: yes but it's a little confusing. Consider a While language (if, assignments, lops, concatenation). Can a universal program written in While language be the semantics? I'm not about this.

Comment: @gandalf61: No, a universal Turing machine is *not* a formalization of Turing machines. That would establish a vicious circle, as you would still have to formalize the universal Turing machine, but you cannot state its properties without having first formalized Turing machines.

Answer (score 2):

The usual definitions of Turing machines *are* given in terms of formal semantics. For instance, the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition) describes Turing machines in precise mathematical formalism. If you are looking for something even more formal, have a look at this [Coq formalization of Turing machines](https://github.com/uds-psl/CoqTM).